# if console.log contains specific words , it should call some function.

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to write a condition if console.log() contains specific sentences/words..if console.log contains specific words , it should call/invoke some function.

Comment: `console.log()` doesn't provide options for callbacks or similar that would let you react to messages. You could instead create your own "log" function, that can handle the inspection before passing along to `console.log()`, and call that function elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `console.log` so that you can implement the condition:

```js
var console = window.console;
//for node.js use global instead of window
//var console = global.console;
console.log = function(msg){
  if(msg.includes('message'))
    myFunc();
}

console.log('Simple message');
function myFunc(){
  alert('function invoked');
}
```